# wget is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, wget

I'm running Jupyter Notebook 6.0.1 via Anaconda Navigator, and was working on a Jupyter Notebook using Python 3. Need help to download data using wget. Appreciate a step-by-step solution as I'm new to coding. Thanks.

The code I typed to install wget:

```
!pip install wget
```

It returns: Requirement already satisfied: wget in c:\users\louie\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.2)

The code to download data:

```
import wget
!wget -q -O 'newyork_data.json' https://cocl.us/new_york_dataset
print('Data downloaded!')
```

I get this error message:

'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[snapshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IAaL.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wget is not recognized as a command even though it is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069086/wget-is-not-recognized-as-a-command-even-though-it-is-installed)

Comment: for windows, you can download wget.exe from https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/   and after downloading move the file wget.exe   to  C:\Windows\System32 or add it  to path in environment variables

Answer (score 9):

```
!pip install wget

!python -m wget -o 'newyork_data.json' https://cocl.us/new_york_dataset
```

or:

```
!pip install wget
import wget
url = 'https://cocl.us/new_york_dataset'
filename = wget.download(url)
print(filename)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: These days running `pip install` inside a notebook should be done without an exclamation point using the magic `%pip install` command to insure installations occur in the environment that the kernel that backs the active notebook runs. See more about the modern magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue then. I did not get the solution but got a workaround, which is using curl in jupyter notebook.
In an answer to this post:
[wget is not recognized as a command even though it is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069086/wget-is-not-recognized-as-a-command-even-though-it-is-installed)

For example

```
!curl -O https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson
```

Comment: I was thinking about this when I run into the same issue but I thought `curl` would have a more different format ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://cocl.us/new_york_dataset.json'
filename = 'newyork.json'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
print('GeoJSON file downloaded!')
ny_geo = r'newyork.json' # geojson file
```

You may use this code as well